# Android: set Background to custom view

Tags: android, android-view

I have created a customView in Android library and extended from AppCompatEditText. In init method I want to set background from my drawable resource.I write this code :

```
public class GrootAnimatedEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
    public GrootAnimatedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public GrootAnimatedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public GrootAnimatedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }
   private void init(Context context) {
        setBackground(R.drawable.roundbg);
    }
}
```

When i put a dot (.) roundbg and any drawable do not suggest to me.I also use :

```
setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundbg));
        //or
setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.roundbg));
```

again do not work! How can I set drawable to my custom TextView background?

**************** Edit ******************

**roundbg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#44433A" />
    <solid android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

Comment: You already create roundbg.xml in drawable folder?

Comment: Can you show us the list of your imports and the contents of your library's drawable folder?

Comment: yes i have created roundbg.xml

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HcW7l84.jpg @ChrisStillwell

Comment: Can you make sure you're importing the correct `R` class? It should be relative to your project. Have you built the project since you added that resource?

Comment: this is my imports: `import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.animation.OvershootInterpolator;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Collection;`

Comment: I have imported R from `com.groot.grootanimatededittext` thats my project

Comment: You are missing `com.groot.grootanimatededittext.R` in the list of imports you supplied.

Comment: Can you share your roundbg?

Comment: Voting to close this as "Off-Topic: Typographical Error" since this just seems to be a missing import.

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: @sayreskabir this should work. Is TextView in your question a typo? Are you trying to set the background to edittext or textview?
And can you post layout file where you are using this view?

Comment: I select invalidate caches and my roundbg is known for my drawable. although i did that before.sorry for late response.Here is new year. thanks for helping so much @ChrisStillwell

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `setBackgroundResource()` or `setBackgroundDrawable()` instead of `setBackground()`.

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText.html#setBackgroundResource(int))